Tempered distributions at non-coinciding points and density of Schwartz functions
In the previous question, I find that situation is much less favorable than expected…. So I add more details to focus on the specific case I have in mind.
Let us consider the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ and denotes its elements as $f(x_1, \dotsc, x_N)$ with $x_1, \dotsc, x_N \in \mathbb{R}^m$. In the original paper Osterwalder and Schrader - Axioms for Euclidean Green's functions on Schwinger functions, the following subspace is introduced:
\begin{equation}
 ^{0}\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN}):= \{ f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN}) \mid f \text{ and  all its derivatives vanish at $(x_1, \dotsc, x_N)$ whenever } x_i=x_j \text{ for some } 1 \leq i < j \leq N \}
\end{equation}
Let $ ^{0}\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$ denote the space of continuous linear functionals on $ ^{0}\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$.
Obviously, each $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ defines an element $T_f \in {^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$ by the formula $T_f (g) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{mN}} fg$ for $g \in  {^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$.
Now, my question is as follows:

Is the above mapping $f \to T_f$ injective?


Is $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ sequentially dense in ${^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$ w.r.t the weak$^*$ topology in the sense that for any $T \in {^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$, we can find a sequence $\{ f_l \} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ with $T_{f_l}(g) \to T(g)$ as $l \to \infty$ for each $g \in {^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$?

I hope that this question is more solid than the previous one.
Add) After all, I am looking for a space of "ordinary functions" injectively and densely embedded in ${^{0}\mathcal{S}}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$. If Schwartz space doesn't work, I hope to know if there is any other candidate.

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}\newcommand\S{\mathcal S}$Yes, the linear mapping $f\mapsto T_f$ is injective.
Indeed, suppose that $T_f=0$ for some $f\in\S(\R^{mN})$.
Consider the open set
$$X:=\{x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)\in\Bbb R^{mN}\colon x_i\ne x_j \text{ if }i\ne j\}.$$
Take any $x\in X$. Then there is a sequence $(g_n)$ in $^0\S(\R^{mN})$ such that eventually (that is, for each large enough $n$) we have $g_n\ge0$, $g_n=0$ outside the open ball $B_x(1/n)$ of radius $1/n$ centered at $x$, and $\int g_n=1$. Then $0=T_f(g_n)=\int fg_n\to f(x)$.
So, $f=0$ on $X$. Therefore and because $f$ is continuous and because $X$ is dense in $\R^{mN}$, we have $f=0$ on $\R^{mN}$. So, the mapping $f\mapsto T_f$ is injective.

Thank you as always! How about sequential density in the weak$^*$ topology?

@Isaac : I think this should also be true, but do not have a complete proof at this point. Since there should be only one question in one post you may want to consider posting the sequential density separately.

Thank you. I will think about the answer myself a bit more and will upload another post if I fail.

It should be remarked that if ${}^0\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ is endowed with the topology induced from $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$, then any $T\in{}^0\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$ admits a(n usually non-unique) continuous linear extension to the whole of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem. In other words, any $T\in{}^0\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$ is the restriction to ${}^0\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})$ of some $\widetilde{T}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{mN})'$. Since $\mathcal{S}$ is weak-* sequentially dense in $\mathcal{S}'$, the result should follow.

I was going to mention the strategy of extension, followed by the usual mollification and truncation to get the approximation in the usual $S'$ but Pedro beat me to it. It's better to say sequentially dense for the strong dual topology, which is a stronger statement anyway, instead of weak-$\ast$ sequentially dense. Note that Hahn-Banach is a cheap solution, the alternative being to note that $T$ has at most algebraic singularities on the big diagonal and therefore admits an extension using resolution of singularities, or Bernstein polynomial techniques. My understanding is that...

...the big diagonal is as hard as it gets from the point of view of resolution of singularities. BTW see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/470858/fulton-macpherson-compactifications-and-wonderful-compactifications-as-relativ   for a new question about resolution of singularities for the big diagonal.

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam well, the whole subject of renormalization of distributions (as done in perturbative QFT) is a constructive form of the Hahn-Banach theorem, as Klaus Hepp put it long ago....

indeed.........

Regarding the use of resolution of singularities in (perturbative) renormalization, although the idea seems natural at first, it's somewhat limited in practice as far as I know (one can only renormalize logarithmic singularities at worst), see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0633
